# Can I delete all files from Temporary Internet Files?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I have opened the following folder in Windows 7 Professional:

```
C:\Users\Igor\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows
```

This folder contains `Temporary Internet Files`, which is 2GB.

I don't use Internet Explorer; how can I delete all files from this directory and is it safe to do so?

Comment: You can use cCleaner

Comment: Both surfasb and Jupotter are right, but I also prefer CCleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use CCleaner ( http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER ).
If you want to remove only the IE files, uncheck all the boxes in the Windows and Application tab, beside the IE temporary files , then analyse and clean.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can manually delete all that is in that folder, I have done it as regular maintenance for many years, some files or folders may be locked if a program is open and using them, just skip them during the delete process.

I keep a shortcut to that folder on my desktop or pinned to my jumplist.

Its faster and more complete than using software to do it.

Some folders and files in there will be replicated by Windows or other programs shortly after deletion or reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use disk cleanup to delete the files.  Yes it is perfectly safe.